# How do I set up CefSharp VS 2017 solution to copy cef.redist and CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess to bin folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

For the past two months I've been working on a C# project in VS2017 using CefSharp.  Things were going well, I had a working app, was adding to it, polishing, etcetera. Then one day, I decided to rename the CefSharp.WinForms.Example project.  Turns out this was not a good idea.  I 
continued for another week or two with no problems, then thought, "it's time to see if I can set up this build environment from scratch."  In the process of doing this, I discovered that CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess (and its components) were no longer being copied to my project' bin directories.  Nor were the files distributed in cef.redist.x86.  So, off to the NuGet package manager... cef.redist.x86 is there (in the NuGet PM), and it looks like its set up correctly.  I've looked at 'build.ps1' and and 'afterbuild.example.ps1' and every other file I can think of,  but I can't figure out how to get the BrowserSubprocess files and CEF distribution to be copied to my bin folders by the build process.  I've been proceeding by copying them into the bin dir "by hand"...

I tried to solution given in "Dependencies not copied to bin folder", i.e., insert this in .csproj file:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

This had no effect.

To shorten a long story into question:

How do I set up the VS 2017 solution to copy these files automatically?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample for a working example. Your description is wordy, doesn't real contain a lot of detail. Are you targeting `x86`, `x64` or `AnyCPU`? Which packages have you actually installed? Including version.

Comment: targeting x86
packages (somewhat abbreviated list):

CefSharp
CefSharp.Core
CefSharp.Example
CefSharp.WinForms
HtmlAgilityPack
Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack
Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell
NewtonSoft.Json
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.SQLite
System.Design
System.Drawing
System.Net.Http
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.Security
System.Windows.Forms
System.Xaml
System.Xml
Windows.Base

Comment: Just the `nuget` packages, not interested in the `references`. Rather than posting as a comment, best to edit your question and add new info rather than posting a wall of text. Start with a dot point list of steps to reproduce what you've done. As it stands it's just too vague, have a read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Remove the wordiness and keep it short and to the point

Comment: Make sure you change the `solution target` to `x86`, not just the project target.

Comment: Way too many steps to make a list here.  As I think I mentioned, I had been working quite some time before I noticed the problem.  So -- I'm going to ask a different question; an answer to that will solve my problem.  Should I edit this question, or post a new one?  And BTW, the solution target is correct.

Comment: Just edit this question if it's on topic. Only the list of steps to reproduce your problem, i.e. the one creating a new solution is relevant. As I've already mention there is a working example available you can compare your solution to.

Comment: Your question is about as clear as mud, think I finally understand. So you've skipped using the official nuget packages and hacked against the master branch? The files are copied internally using a props file see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Native.props

Comment: Be warned the 3.3497.1840 packages will dissapear from the myget feed in a few weeks, I strongly advise against using a custom build, using the official nuget packages is the only supported option.

Answer (score 0):

The simple kludge is to add the following Build Events/Post-build event command line:

```
xcopy /Y /S $(SolutionDir)packages\cef.redist.x86.3.3497.1840\CEF\*.* $(TargetDir)
```

Not what I was looking for, but it works.